# gradle command is failing as it is not able to start daemon

Tags: java, windows, gradle

I am trying to run the gradle command. This has worked initially. However it has started failing after some time, as it is not able to start daemon. I am using Gradle 2.5 with IBM jdk 1.6 on Windows 7 Enterprise.

I have cleaned up the .gradle directory in my user home directory and restarted my system.

This is working fine on my friends machine with same versions.
Please help.

```
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not start Gradle daemon.
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startProcess(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:137)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:114)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:109)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:87)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:117)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:77)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:23
7)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:21
0)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.EOFException
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonStartupCommunication.readDiagnostics(DaemonStartupCommunication.ja
va:100)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonGreeter.parseDaemonOutput(DaemonGreeter.java:40)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startProcess(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:133)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readBoolean(DataInputStream.java:238)
        at org.gradle.internal.serialize.InputStreamBackedDecoder.readBoolean(InputStreamBackedDecoder.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.serialize.AbstractDecoder.readNullableString(AbstractDecoder.java:53)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonStartupCommunication.readDiagnostics(DaemonStartupCommunication.ja
va:85)
        ... 26 more
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not certain about your scenario (and about IBM jdk) but whenever daemon, or in general any otherwise perfectly working build, suddenly stops working for me, I try two things.

1. `gradle myTask --no-daemon` to run build without daemon in order to ensure if it is indeed a problem with daemon.
2. `gradle --stop` to kill any existing daemon and then try build again.

There is a word of caution about using daemons on Windows in the [gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html):

> It is also possible to destabilize the Daemon (and build environment in general) by running builds that do not release resources correctly. This is a particularly poignant problem when using Microsoft Windows as it is less forgiving of programs that fail to close files after reading or writing.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I tried to run the gradle --no-daemon it works. gradle --stop is stopping the hanging daemons but does not resolve the issue. I still need to use --no-daemon. This is also happening with Oracle JDK now. It worked yesterday, today after restarting my machine it is giving the same problem.

Comment: So the problem is not with jdk or your build script. It is gradle daemon on windows that's possibly unstable on Windows. Can you see if your code releases files correctly (in `finally` blocks). You could create a sample project reproducing problem and log an issue here: https://issues.gradle.org/

Answer (score 1):

I had originally used JDK 9.0.4 from the provided [tar.gz build](https://jdk.java.net/archive). As log output I received:

```
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not start Gradle daemon
```

After the installation of the [exe installation package](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase9-archive-downloads.html) of JDK 9.0.4 the error message was done.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue while running gradle tasks. Deleting gradle cache (~/.gradle/cache) solved it..!!